# Access UIViewController from UITabBarController and UINavigationController

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an application based on UITabbar and the view hierarchy as follows.

UITabBarController ----> UINavigationController ----> UIViewController

I have push notification payload which will open specific UIViewController, i can explicitly open UIViewController directly using view controller Storyboard ID, but tabBar and Navbar won't show.
How can I go to specific View Controller and show TabBar and NavController from AppDelegate didReceiveRemoteNotifications.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you check my answer?

Comment: sure, I have few more question for you @FedericoMalagoni

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to instantiate all of your VC and set all of them as root of his predecessor :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let mainStoryboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let yourVC = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourVC_Identifier");
    let yourNavController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourNAV_Identifier") as! UINavigationController
    let yourTabController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("YourTAB_Identifier") as! UITabBarController

    yourNavController.setViewControllers([yourVC], animated: false)
    yourTabController.setViewControllers([yourNavController], animated: false)


    self.window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
    self.window?.rootViewController = yourTabController
    self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()



    return true
}
```

Comment: hi @Federico Malagoni, your answer is awesome, the code works like I expected, but it seems like i can't use popToRootViewController after the VC is initiated. why is that?

Comment: I didn't understood your question. Could you create new question ?

Answer (score 0):

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow]` has a property `.rootViewController`. Presumably thats your tab bar. On this controller, you can set the active tab and switch out view controllers with the `.viewControllers` property. Now assuming one of these is your `UINavigationController` that should also have a property `.rootViewController`. Instantiate from the storyboard and either set the root or push the view controller on top of the navigation controller.

Comment: could you show the pseudocode in swift, please? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Follow the hierarchy from App Delegate programmatically. 
In case your entry point is from the Storyboard, setup a `UIWindow` in your `AppDelegate` so you could set the `UITabBarController` as the following.

```
//self.tabBarController is you TabBar from Storyboard, or programatically initialized
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
```

Then whenever you have a notification in `didReceiveRemoteNotifications` sort the notification out by type, and find the view controller:

```
//Let's say the View Controller being accessed is in the first position of the stack of viewcontroller from UITabBarController & UINavigationController 
UINavigationController *navViewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers.firstObject;
UIViewController *accessedViewController = navViewController.viewcontroller.firstObject;
```